# Show only the time from mySQL timestamp field using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I `echo['time']` from the Database i get for example

```
2012-07-21 17:00:00
```

my question is how should I show only the hours and minutes for every timestamp I get? (17:00)

Answer (score 13):

You can select it as:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(`dateColumn`, '%H:%i') FROM ...
```

or use `strtotime` as mentioned in other answers.

If you did want the full time with seconds, you could also use:

```
SELECT TIME(`dateColumn`) FROM ...
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 6):

You should parse it properly and echo what you want with the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class:

```
$time = '2012-07-21 17:00:00';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time, new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York'));
echo $date->format( 'H:i'); // Will print 17:00
```

[Demo](http://viper-7.com/4NO2SZ)

Answer (score 3):

You could do what Kris said
`echo date('H:i', strtotime('2012-07-21 17:00:00'));`

but It is better practice to process from MySQL if possible,

`select date_format(time, '%H:%i') from table;`

shoul retrieve the data and format it to you good to go!

Answer (score 2):

`echo date('H:i', strtotime($row['time']));`

or you could format in your sql query with [datetime functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('H:i', strtotime('2012-07-21 17:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use my own code. try this..
follow these steps:- 
1. Select time from database table assuming:-  $time = $row['time'];
2. create a php file with the name :- "time.php" 
3. paste the following code into time.php

```
  <?php
$ct= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$now = new DateTime("$ct");
$ref = new DateTime("$time");
$diff = $now->diff($ref);
$y=$diff->y;
$m=$diff->m;
$d=$diff->d;
$h=$diff->h;
$i=$diff->i;
$s=$diff->s;
if($m>12)
{
echo $y;
echo " year ago";
}
elseif($m<1 && $d<1 && $h<1 && $i<1 && $s<60)
{
echo $s;
echo " sec ago";
}
elseif($m<1 && $d<1 && $h<1 && $i<60)
{
echo $i;
echo " mins ago";
}
elseif($m<1 && $d<1 && $h<48)
{
echo $h;
echo " hrs ago";
}
elseif($m<1 && $d<30 && $h<24)
{
    if($d==1)
    {
        echo 24+$h." hrs ago";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $d;
        echo " days ago";
    }
}
elseif($m<=12)
{
    if($m > 0)
    {
        echo $m;
        echo " Month ago";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $d;
        echo " days ago";
    }       

}

?> 
 <?php include "time.php";?> //use include/require function where you want to display time ago...
```

4. Simply include the file in the other php file where you want to display the time in the format 
   1 day ago/ 30 day ago.....sec ago..hrs ago..month ago and many more..